# Which event used to be called when call is rejected?

Tags: android

I want to perform some action when reject button is pressed for any incoming call. I have gone through the official documentation [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED) but it doesn't satisfy my need.

I have tried with this with no success.

```
public class Call_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Context ctx;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ctx = context;
        OutgoingIncomingCallListener phoneListener = new OutgoingIncomingCallListener();
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        if (intent.getAction()
                .equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            telephony.listen(phoneListener,
                    PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }

    }

    class OutgoingIncomingCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        public boolean wasRinging;

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                wasRinging = true;
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Log.i("", "  ***********  OFFHOOK  ********");
                wasRinging = true;
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                if (wasRinging) {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx,
                            "Your call is disconnected by receiver", 10000)
                            .show();
                }
                wasRinging = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's showing me toast when receiver rejects the call but I want to do it from caller side.
So all I want to find the event when someone presses reject button for any incoming call.

How do I do this?